# Django limit acces to data for owner

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

i'm trying to make query for user in Django, but still every user can see all data from data base. I've tried with filters, q objects, but none of these helped me.

**Here is my model:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.bookIdent} - belonging to: {self.user}'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookIdent = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookshelf = models.ForeignKey(BookShelf, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def total_info(cls):
        return cls.objects.aggregate(book_counter=Count('id'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Books"
```

**And my views:**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):

    context = {'segment': 'index'}
    html_template = loader.get_template('dashboard.html')

    context.update(dict(Book.total_info()))
    context['Book'] = set_pagination(request,Book.objects.all().
        filter(user=request.user), item_numer=10)

    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

I would like to make query that only user from book class could see his books.

**Template:**

```
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="card card-stats">

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">Book quantity:</h5>

                                        <span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0">

                                            {{ book_counter|default:0 }}

                                        </span>

                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views.py, you can do

```
books = Book.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context['book_counter'] = books.count()
```

Comment: I did it and it changed nothing

Comment: Can you share your template?

Comment: Just added to original question